# how to move text after the circel using html and css

Tags: html, css

Hi I have created circle. I wan to move the text after the circle.

My plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/48EpeXDtj9sgAp2hiyF3?p=preview

Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#circle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
    #text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 60%;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="circle"><div id="text">T</div></div>ext


</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Vinoth

Comment: After to the right?  Or after below?

Comment: @DMrFrost after to right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they are both block elements, they will both take up 100% width (thus display on a new line). The fix for this is to use either inline elements, or set your elements to `display:inline-block`

You will then need to fix the vertical-align of your elements

updated plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SIrVjrRB9CW82BnTcUd1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well your question, you can try with css :before wich will make your html cleaner.

```css
div#circle {
  padding-left:18px ;
  height:30px ;
  position:relative ;
  padding-top:5px ;
  z-index:2 ;
  box-sizing:border-box ;
}

div#circle:before {
  content:' ' ;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top:0 ;
  left:0 ;
  z-index:1 ;
}

div#circle span {
  color:#FFF ;
  position:relative ;
  z-index:3 ;
  display:inline-block ;
  width:12px ;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"><span>D</span>ext</div>
```

Comment: i believe the circle should contain the first letter

Comment: I've edited the answer but it could be not really precise depending on your first caracter and font size. You may need to adjust padding-left:18px in div#circle, and div#circle span width.

Comment: can do something a bit cleaner with the same markup but different css approach: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZowEz this will adjust for any letter

Comment: Yeah if you want the first letter to be in the center of the circle then it's absolutly correct. In first hand i didn't knew you wanted a letter in the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<style>
#circle {
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
  #text {
   top: 25%;
   color: #fff;
   float:left;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left:10px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Wrap the element in tags with applicable classes to target as
    selectors for given styles.

**2.** Nest `absolute` elements within `relative` parent element, `absolute` element positions are now "relative" to parent element.

```css
#circle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
.text-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
.text-outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="circle">
  <div class="text-inner">T</div>
  <div class="text-outer">ext</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#circle {
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 30px;
  text-align:center;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  }
 #text {
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  color: #fff;
}

#ext{
/* if don't  want any space then remove this */
position:relative;
}

div {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="circle"><div id="text">T</div></div> <div id="ext">  ext </div>
</body>
```